# Как в одной программы сделать вторую

Tags: c++, c, компиляция

Есть программа exe (консольная) в которой просят ввести имя, после этого эта программа создает другую программу exe, которая просто выводит в окне введенное имя.
Как это можно сделать?
Думал сделать так чтобы при открытие первой программы создавался исходник второй программы и при введении имени изменялся бы исходник, и скомпилировать исходник.
Но Есть пару проблем:

1. У человека может не быть компилятора gcc или другие
2. Добавится исходный файл
3. Человек увидет исходный  код(хоть и проблемы в этом и нет)

Comment: А чем передача имени в командной строке или - экзотика - в переменной среды, или еще как не устраивает?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте бинарник, который выводит имя. Это не сложно. В этом файле у Вас будет буфер, где собственно должна хранится строка с именем. Сделайте ее побольше - думаю 4096 символов скорее всего хватит. И заполните какими то уникальными символами, к примеру, AAAAAAAAA....

Теперь, основная програма может просто открыть данную програму как бинарный файл, найти эту строку (можно конечно и захардкодить позицию, но это как то не то) и просто туда поверх записывает нужную строку-имя с нулевым символом в конце. Все. Но это теория.

Практика.

Вторая программа может выглядеть вот так

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char name[4096] = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
    puts(name);
}
```

дальше компилируем и пользуемся [xxd -i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155578/which-program-creates-a-c-array-given-any-file/2339839) и получаем программу в виде массива. Ну а далее дело техники.

Comment: Думаю лучше уточнить почему именно бинарник....

Comment: почему открывать как бинарник?